# ASP.Net Application Doubling Controls on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

When my page hits postback, I end up with double the controls on my page. The first half of controls have both the original values and the new values listed in all textboxes, and the second set have all of the old values only. When stepping through my code it seems to not encounter the same problem, but running it normally it happens every time.

Here is my Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(Session["level"]) == 0)
                {
                    FillStoreDropDown();
                    FillTypeDropDown();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
            }
        }

        addProductElements();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["LoadExisting"] != null)
            {
                LoadExisting();
                CheckType();
            }
        }
    }
```

The addProductElements() creates only one set of controls each time it runs, and works great every other time. The only time this issue actually comes up is when I run a save method and then change the value in a textbox. Below is my textbox_changed code as well as a recursive search that I'm using:

```
        // finds controls that were created dynamically
    private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
    {
        if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

        foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
        {
            Control controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
            if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // to update total label after typing in a product count check box
    protected void productCount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = myPanel.Controls.Count;
        string myString = (((Control)sender).Parent.ID).ToString();

        myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "[^0-9]", "");

        Label totalPrice = (Label)FindControlRecursive(Page, ("lblProdSumTotal" + myString));
        Label prodPrice = (Label)FindControlRecursive(Page, ("lblProdPrice" + myString));
        TextBox prodCount = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(Page, ("txtProdCount" + myString));
        Label promoDiscount = (Label)FindControlRecursive(Page, ("lblPromoDisc" + myString));

        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(prodCount.Text, out n))
        {
            if (promoDiscount.Text != "")
            {
                totalPrice.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(prodCount.Text)) * ((Convert.ToDecimal(prodPrice.Text)) - (Convert.ToDecimal(promoDiscount.Text)))).ToString("c");

            }
            else
            {
                totalPrice.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(prodCount.Text)) * (Convert.ToDecimal(prodPrice.Text))).ToString("c");

            }
            UpdateIndLabelTotal();
        }
        else
        {
            lblNotice.Attributes.Add("style", "label-danger");
            lblNotice.Text = "Invalid entry.";
        }
    }
```

Edit: Here is the addProductElements():

```
        protected void addProductElements()
    {

        // set up an array of all products through sql connection
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlCommand command = null;

        String queryString;

        List<string> allProducts = new List<string>();
        List<string> allUPCs = new List<string>();
        List<string> allPrices = new List<string>();
        List<List<string>> promotionItems = new List<List<string>>();

        queryString = @"SELECT products.productid, products.upc, products.productname, products.sapnum, products.price FROM Products order by products.productname";
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            allProducts.Add(reader["ProductName"].ToString());
            allUPCs.Add(reader["UPC"].ToString());
            allPrices.Add(reader["Price"].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();

        queryString = @"SELECT * FROM Promotions WHERE StoreID = @StoreID and StartDate <= getdate() and EndDate >= getdate()";
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("storeID", Convert.ToInt16(ddlCompanyStores.SelectedValue));
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
            tempList.Add(reader["PromotionID"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["StoreID"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["Parent_CompanyID"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["UPC"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["DiscountAmount"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["StartDate"].ToString());
            tempList.Add(reader["EndDate"].ToString());
            promotionItems.Add(tempList);
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();

        string[] myProds = allProducts.ToArray();

        // set up a loop
        // for each in loop, create controls with loop index name id
        // add each to array

        PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();

        int numlabels = myProds.GetUpperBound(0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= numlabels; i++)
        {
            Panel prodPanel = new Panel();
            Label productName = new Label();
            Label productID = new Label();
            TextBox productCount = new TextBox();
            Label productOperator = new Label();
            Label productPrice = new Label();
            Label promotionOperator = new Label();
            Label promotionDiscount = new Label();
            Label productSumVal = new Label();
            Label productSumTotal = new Label();

            prodPanel.ID = "Panel" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #E7E4E3;margin-top:15px;padding-top:10px");
            prodPanel.Attributes.Add("Class", "container");

            productName.Text = allProducts[i];
            productName.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            productName.ID = "lblProdName" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productName);

            productID.Text = allUPCs[i];
            productID.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
            productID.ID = "lblProdID" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productID);

            prodPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            productCount.Text = "0";
            productCount.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            productCount.ID = "txtProdCount" + i.ToString();
            productCount.AutoPostBack = true;
            productCount.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
            productCount.TextChanged += new EventHandler(productCount_TextChanged);

            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productCount);

            productOperator.Text = " x ";
            productOperator.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            productOperator.ID = "lblProdOper" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productOperator);

            productPrice.Text = allPrices[i];
            productPrice.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            productPrice.ID = "lblProdPrice" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productPrice);

            promotionOperator.Text = "";
            promotionOperator.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            promotionOperator.ID = "lblPromoOper" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(promotionOperator);

            promotionDiscount.Text = "";
            promotionDiscount.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            promotionDiscount.ID = "lblPromoDisc" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(promotionDiscount);

            foreach (List<string> l in promotionItems)
            {
                if (l[1] == ddlCompanyStores.SelectedValue)
                {
                    if (l[3] == allUPCs[i])
                    {
                        promotionOperator.Text = " - ";

                        promotionDiscount.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(l[4]).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            productSumVal.Text = " = ";
            productSumVal.Attributes.Add("style", "float:left");
            productSumVal.ID = "lblProdSum" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productSumVal);

            productSumTotal.Text = "$0.00";
            productSumTotal.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
            productSumTotal.ID = "lblProdSumTotal" + i.ToString();
            prodPanel.Controls.Add(productSumTotal);

            myPanel.Controls.Add(prodPanel);
            myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think we might need to see `addProductElements()`.

Comment: I've added it in now. It's a little long, but hopefully something there is causing this!

Answer (score 0):

Any time page loads Page_Load will work.
So that you use;

`if(!IsPostBack)`

But  `addProductElements();` is not inside `if(!IsPostBack)`, so it will work any time page loads. Whether it is postback or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt16(Session["level"]) == 0)
            {
                FillStoreDropDown();
                FillTypeDropDown();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
        }

        addProductElements();

        if (Session["LoadExisting"] != null)
        {
            LoadExisting();
            CheckType();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if it is in (!IsPostback) then it won't recreate the controls after postback and everything will be removed, correct? It seems like it either isn't removing the controls or it is actually creating twice as many after postback.